# How to fetch the most recently added Date from the table

Tags: java, selenium

Scenario:

I have a Screen where i need to enter the Date by incrementing the Date by 10 days ....
After entering the Date and saving the entered Date could come anywhere in the table.
My Question is how do i fetch the newly entered date everytime from the table and store it so that with that date i can increment by date by 10.

Any leads can add more info

This is my Code:

```
List<WebElement> Date = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table//tr/td[contains(@class,'mat-column-lastValidityDate')last()]")); = This will read all the rows of the Column Last Validity Date
```

If you above code - I initially fetched the Last row Date always as all the Newly Added  rows would appear Last

and then - I get the

```
Datetext - String datetext = Date.get(i).getText();
```

And then i navigate to the Create Screen:

```
String NewbtElem = AppXPathsConstants.buttonXpath_replace.replace("XXXX", "New");
                    clickOnButton(driver, NewbtElem);
```

After Naigating to the Create Screen - I enter the below code in order to Increment the Date:

```
    System.out.println("Date before Addition: "+datetext);

                    //Specifying date format that matches the given date
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    SimpleDateFormat outputDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

                    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

                    try{

                        //Setting the date to the given date

                        c.setTime(sdf.parse(datetext));



                    }catch(ParseException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    //Number of Days to add
                    int daysToIncrement = 10;
                    c.add(Calendar.DATE, daysToIncrement);  
                    //Date after adding the days to the given date

                    //String newDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
                    //System.out.println("Get the New Date:"+newDate);


                    String newDate = outputDateFormat.format(c.getTime());

                    System.out.println("Print the latest date:"+newDate);
After which i enter the new date as seen in the below code:
inputEntry(driver, columnInputEntryXpath_replace.replace("XXXX","Last Validity Date"), newDate);
```

After Making Modification to the Code as given below this is how it is :

```
List<WebElement> Date = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table//tr/td[contains(@class,'mat-column-lastValidityDate')]"));
                            
                    final String DATE_PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd";
                    LocalDate maxDate = getRows()
                            .stream()
                            .map(
                                    webElement -> LocalDate.parse(
                                            getDateAsText(WebElement),
                                            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
                                    )
                            )
                    .max(LocalDate::compareTo).get();
                    
                    LocalDate addedDate = maxDate.plusDays(10);
                    System.out.println(addedDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_PATTERN)));

Question is - List<WebElement> getRows(); i actually fetch the rows like int rows = Date.size(); so this being the case how do i getRows();
```

Comment: W need details, otherwise the answer is "you should make some code for that"

Comment: Do you have a screenshot? Your question is pretty unclear, sorry...

Comment: @deHaar - added screenshot- so as you see in the screenshot in the 3rd row i have my data - which has the LastValidity date. Next i should read that date and then navigate to the Create Screen and with that date i need to increment date by 10.The only part where iam not able to get an idea is how to read my date

Comment: OK, thanks for the screenshot... What's the exact problem here? Possibly, you might have to fetch all the dates, sort them and take the most recent one (if I got anything right here).

Comment: @deHaar - unfourtunately i dont have the sorting in this screen .If there was sorting then i would have sorted the column and taken the date so my question is how do i fetch my date alone.The newly added date could come in any row in the table..is there any other ways

Comment: That means you have to fetch **all the rows**, sort the dates (in Java) and get the most recent one... Can you show us your code that takes a row but not the newest one?

Comment: Since you know what you enter why wouldn't you just use this in the locator saying like "fetch a row where the date is what I have entered"?

Comment: @AlexeyR. I think OP has to take the most recent date and add 10 days, then enter it again, but I might be wrong since the question is really unclear.

Comment: @deHaar- //table//tr/td[contains(@class,'mat-column-lastValidityDate')] this will go to all the rows and read the Last Validity Date Column - and your understanding of the scenario is right need to take the most recent date and then add 10 days

Comment: @deHaar-and 3rd row last column has my date entered..hope iam clear now and any inputs pls

Comment: You can parse those dates using a `java.time.LocalDate` and then sort them (they are comparable). That way, you should get the most recent date.

Comment: @deHaar - how to parse using java.time.LocalDate and compare and get the most recent one  - any inputs will be helpful

Comment: @deHaar - String str = "1986-04-08 12:30";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(str, formatter); - is this the way you are saying if yes then in this case how do pass my captured dates in String str =

Comment: Yes, looks ok... I thought about a `LocalDate` because your `String` values in the screenshot have the form `"uuuu-MM-dd"` resp. `"yyyy-MM-dd"` but if there is a time of day, too, take a `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: @deHaar - There is no time and wanted to know what will be the value of String str = ? bz in the example they have entered a date but i cannot enter  the date since iam reading all the rows

Comment: Let's say you get the `String date = "2021-09-30";` from a row. You would parse it like `LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(date);`. I don't know if you want to store them in some `Collection`, but it would be a way to get the sorting right.

Comment: @deHaar -is it possible to give me the code not able to figure out about how to deal with this

Comment: That requires at least some of the code you have written so far. Can you post a snippet? I cannot guess how you are handling the rows...

Comment: @deHaar -List<WebElement> Date = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table//tr/td[contains(@class,'mat-column-lastValidityDate')]"));

Comment: @deHaar - This will read all the values in the column Last Validity date..... actually i had created a code first where List<WebElement> Date = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table//tr/td[contains(@class,'mat-column-lastValidityDate')]last()"] this would fetch the last row value and then

Comment: @deHaar-for(int i=0; i<Date.size(); i++){

          
     String datetext = Date.get(i).getText(); would give the date and after which i use that date and add 10 days SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
     SimpleDateFormat outputDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

     Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

     try{

      //Setting the date to the given date

      c.setTime(sdf.parse(datetext));



     }catch(ParseException e){
      e.printStackTrace();
     }

Comment: //Number of Days to add
     int daysToIncrement = 10;
     c.add(Calendar.DATE, daysToIncrement);  
     String newDate = outputDateFormat.format(c.getTime());

     System.out.println("Print the latest date:"+newDate);

Comment: @deHaar - this is what i initally did to fetch the date and then increment by 10 and then there was change in the functionaliy where the date appeared anywhere in the table as a result of which i was stuck so this is the code ... please let me know if you need the html as well.. or in case you want the link to the app can give

Comment: OK, this question is now totally unreadable for any other user than us. Can you please include the code snippets and the additional information as an [edit]? Otherwise this question will likely get closed... I'll try to find out how to get the latest date meanwhile.

Comment: @Adding code in the Question

Comment: That will make the code snippet(s) a lot more readable and increase the probabilty that other people will read and help.

Comment: @deHaar- Added the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have a method `List<WebElement> getRows();` that returns rows of your table and method `String getDateAsText(WebElement row)` that returns date value as a `String` from a particular table row. Say also your date pattern is `year-month-day`. Then you fetch max date as:

```java
final String DATE_PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd";
LocalDate maxDate = getRows()
        .stream()
        .map(
                webElement -> LocalDate.parse(
                        getDateAsText(webElement),
                        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_PATTERN)
                )
        )
.max(LocalDate::compareTo).get();
LocalDate addedDate = maxDate.plusDays(10);
System.out.println(addedDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_PATTERN)));
```

If you have already fetched dates like `List<WebElement> dates = ...` then you would use this:

```java
LocalDate maxDate = dates
        .stream()
        .map(
                webElement -> LocalDate.parse(
                        webElement.getText(),
                        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_PATTERN)
                )
        )
        .max(LocalDate::compareTo).get();
```

Comment: -have a question - after i get the Max date by using the above code how do i fetch the date and pass it as a String ... Say i want it this way String datetext = maxdate.getText(); and also how do i pass getRows() bz if you see my code it has List<WebElement> Date

Comment: @ Alexey RS - .. Now this is my Code: List<WebElement> Date = Xpath of the Date column where it will read all the rows which has Date and then you say List<WebElement> getRows(); = i dont get this part  bz to return the no of rows  i have given as int rowcount = Date.size()-... so how do i List<WebELemnt>getRows()

Comment: I'm not getting what your code is doing. It is poorly formatted and won't even compile. Just rework your code to meet the structure of my example.

Comment: moreover Date field i make input Entry and need to Pass that as well which i have given in the question section

Comment: You have max date as a proper text string. Use it in your locators.

Comment: ok but List<WebElement> getRows(); is still confusing dont understand how to get this

Comment: have added my queries in the question section – 
@Alexey R

Comment: @ Alexey R - getting a Error:Cannot infer type argument(s) for <R> map(Function<? super T,? extends R>)  LocalDate maxDate = Date
                .stream()
                .map(
                        webElement -> LocalDate.parse(
                                getDateAsText(WebElement),
                                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
                        )
                )

Comment: Sorry i think i missed one code will upadate after runnig the script

Comment: @
Alexey R.-have one more clarification - In the Web Table the Date format appears as yyyy-MM-dd but in the Create Scree while entering the Date - The Date should be entered in MM-DD-YYYY so this being the case how will i convert the given date to MM-DD-YYY format .... while entering the date can you please let me know on this

Comment: @ Alexey R - found the solution for that as well Thanks again for the Help